# Converting object to long

Tags: c#

I have the following function:

```
    public virtual long AsLong(object originalValue,long defaultValue)
    {
        double buffer = defaultValue;
        if (originalValue != null)
        {
            double result;
            var readValueIsconverted = double.TryParse(originalValue.ToString(), out result);
            if (readValueIsconverted)
                buffer = result;
        }

        var roundedValue = Math.Round(buffer, 0);
        var convertedValue = (long) roundedValue;
        return convertedValue;
    }
```

I have used double in order to allow conversion of 14.4!
I have the following failing test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void CanConvertLongMaxValue()
    {
        var cellValue = new Converter();
        const long longValue = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
        var result = cellValue.AsLong(longValue, 12);

        Assert.Equal(longValue, result);

    }
```

I have traced the code and roundedValue is positive but the convertedValue is negative. so what is the problem?

Comment: why are you parsing as double in order to return a long?

Comment: Perhaps see [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) .. or [`Convert.ToInt64(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c5w856c.aspx) ..

Comment: because it is possible to pass for example 13.4 as parameter. if i have used long for the buffer i missed this possibility.

Comment: long roundedValue = (long)Math.Round(myDoubleValue, 0);

Comment: @MitchWheat I do not get it. I have done the same thing. Don't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to hold an integer value with 19 significant digits (in decimal) in a `double` which has [15-16 significant digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Hence, it's not possible to represent the value exactly in the `double`. Apparently rounding causes the value to overflow when converted into a long, making it a negative value.

You can confirm this like so:

```
var convertedValue = checked((long)roundedValue);
```

If you absolutely must deal with this case, I would suggest using [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of double, or splitting the string on the decimal point (or whatever is used in your locale) and dealing with rounding that way.

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of your `originalValue`. Its compile-time type is `object`, but what is the real type at run-time? If it's a boxed number type, there's no need to call `.ToString()` followed by `TryParse`. It is better to unbox directly to the correct type (especially if it is always the same run-time type) and then convert to another numerical type if necessary.

If you send a `long` with many digits, like `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` which is the same as `long.MaxValue`, through a `double`, note that a `long` has approximately 10 bits' higher precision than a `double`. Technically, that's because a `double` uses 11 bits for the exponent but doesn't have to store the most significant bit.

At the value of `long.MaxValue`, the precision of a `double` changes because the exponent goes up by one when we pass a power of two. `double` values just below `long.MaxValue` have a precision of 1024. This means that only whole multiples of 1024 can be represented. Not surprisingly, `double` values just *above* `long.MaxValue` have a precision of 2048. And of course the precision of the integer type `long` is always exactly 1.

Here are the three nearest `double` under and the three over `long.MaxValue`:

```
9.22337203685477'27'36 E+18
9.22337203685477'37'60 E+18
9.22337203685477'47'84 E+18
---
9.22337203685477'58'08 E+18  <-- two to the 63rd power
9.22337203685477'78'56 E+18
9.22337203685477'99'04 E+18
```

When you convert `long.MaxValue`, that is `9223372036854775807` to `double`, the nearest representable is `9.223372036854775808E+18` which is `1.0` too large. Its string representation with `.ToString()` will show only 15 digits, while `.ToString("R")` will show 17 digits (the apostrophes `'` in my list above). When converting the `double` `` `9.223372036854775808E+18 `` back to `long`, we get an overflow exception because the number is `1.0` too big. You can still convert the number to `ulong`, of course, which should reveal the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

You should check, if provided parameter is `long` at the first place:

```
public virtual long AsLong(object originalValue,long defaultValue)
{
    if(originalValue.GetType() == typeof(long))
        return (long) originalValue;

    double buffer = defaultValue;

    ...
}
```

Otherwise you can loose some information on `long` to `double` conversion.